# Assign variable to attribute in angular

Tags: angularjs, binding

I want to assign the `config` to be something like this `config_{{$index}}_{{a.methodName}}` as shown in the code below, but it didn't really work as expected. Any idea?

```
<div data-ng-repeat="a in b">
    <highchart config="config_{{$index}}_{{a.methodName}}"></highchart>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle?

Comment: wouldn't it be easier with an array ? this way you could call `config[$index][a.methodeName]`